Understanding and deriving the functional derivative
In my book the following happens:
$$\int\frac{\delta F}{\delta y(x)}\eta(x) \text{d}x = \int \bigg[\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}\eta(x) + \frac{\partial G}{\partial y'}\eta'(x)\bigg]\text{d}x,$$
where
$$ F[y] =\int G(y(x), y'(x), x) \text{d}x.$$
From reverse engineering we must have
$$\frac{\delta F}{\delta y(x)} = \frac{\partial G}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial G}{\partial y'}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}$$
I have two questions:

where has the integral gone? surely:
$$\frac{\delta F}{\delta y(x)}= \int \frac{\partial G}{\partial y}  + \frac{\partial G}{\partial y'}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\text{d}x$$

how do I derive the relation?
I have started with
$$\delta F = \frac{\partial G}{\partial y} \delta y + \frac{\partial G}{\partial y'} \delta y' = \frac{\partial G}{\partial y} \delta y + \frac{\partial G}{\partial y'} \delta y'\frac{\delta y}{\delta y}$$
Therefore


$$\frac{\delta F}{\delta y(x)} = \frac{\partial G}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial G}{\partial y'} \delta y'\frac{1}{\delta y}$$
Then working on the last term
$$\frac{\delta y'}{\delta y} = \delta \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{1}{\delta y} = \frac{d}{dx}?$$
I was a mathematician years ago and I feel like some of the steps I have made would get me beaten up by my analysis professor. Especially the last few steps. The final step I have essentially swapped $\delta$ and $d$.
There are other ways to answer these questions, I have no doubt. I would really like to maintain my approach however. Is there a way I can properly justify my steps in answering question 2? etc.

"From reverse engineering we must have..." and why is that exactly? The integral doesn't just magically disappear. For example $\int_0^1 x^2,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1\frac{2x}{3},\mathrm dx$ but obviously we know that $x\mapsto x^2$ and $x\mapsto\frac{2x}{3}$ are different functions

If you want to formalize what you're doing I think you have to start talking about distributions, and that probably also holds the answer to your questions

The integral should not be there. By looking at the proof of Euler-Lagrange equation
$$
\int \frac{\delta F}{\delta y} \eta(x) dx =\frac{d}{d\epsilon} F[y(x)+\epsilon\eta(x)]_{\epsilon=0}
$$
So I think it is just a problem of notation
If this true we get the result as
$$
\int \frac{d}{d\epsilon} G(y(x)+\epsilon \eta(x), y'(x)+ \epsilon \eta'(x),x) dx=\int \eta(x) \frac{\partial G}{\partial y} + \eta'(x) \frac{\partial G}{\partial y'} dx
$$
By the definition of total derivative and the chain rule.
